# Accounting for dividends of stocks held for 3rd party

Tags: dividends, accounting, double-entry, liability

Assuming I hold a number of stocks in a brokerage account for a 3rd party which pays dividends. The broker automatically deducts taxes and debits the remaining money in the account. How do I accurately record the liability after taxes in my books?

Lets say I have the following accounts:

| Type | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Assest | Brokerage-Account |
| Expenses | Taxes |
| Liability | 3rdParty |
| Income | Dividends |

E.g. say 100$ dividends, and 15$ deducted in taxes.

If I record this as

| Account | Dr | Cr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dividends | 100 |  |
| Taxes |  | 15 |
| Brokerage Account |  | 85 |
| 3rdParty | 85 |  |
| ?????? |  | 85 |

In which account do I record the corresponding 85$?

Comment: Can you give more details about why you are holding anything in your name for someone else?

Comment: Instead of `Accounts Payable`, maybe `Dividends Payable`?

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica is that necessary?  Maybe it's for the kids' education or daughter's wedding.

Comment: @RonJohn - Money I saved for my daughter's college education, I just paid the taxes on each year, myself. Money I hold for a friend? Wouldn't the accounting be a bit different? 2 other members agreed the detail would be useful.

Comment: @JTP-ApologisetoMonica sure, it's for my little niece. I invest my money for her and will gift her the gains and stocks when she turns 18. I pay the taxes but want to record what I "owe" her, if that makes sense.